# How to show an array in json,when my table contains single record

Tags: wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I'm having trouble understanding why dataTables is refusing to show a single row of data but it works perfectly fine for any data sets greater than 1 row.  I don't think this shows the issue either, as I think it's the format of the JSON message at fault here or as per my view filter is not working so.....directly it is going to then condition and returning the values from DBtable

This is a 10 record JSON response which works OK:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Getmessage_seq" onError="fault" trace="disable">
   <property name="CONTENT_TYPE" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
   <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xpath="s://logid/text()=' '">
      <then>
         <payloadFactory>
            <format>
               <ResponseJSON xmlns="">
                  <Exception>NO Data Found In Database</Exception>
                  <Status>404</Status>
               </ResponseJSON>
            </format>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send/>
      </then>
      <else>
         <property name="AAR" expression="count(//s:Datalist)" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <enrich>
            <source clone="true" type="custom" xpath="//s:Datalist"/>
            <target action="replace" type="property" property="List"/>
         </enrich>
         <property name="CONTENT_TYPE" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <payloadFactory>
            <format>
               <ResponseJSON xmlns="">
                  <Body>$1</Body>
                  <Status>200</Status>
                  <Total>$2</Total>
               </ResponseJSON>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg expression="get-property('List')"/>
               <arg expression="get-property('AAR')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send/>
      </else>
   </filter>
</sequence>
```

`enter code here`

finally,when my table contains more than one record data is showing as an array in json,when it turns to one record data is not showing as an array in json.

Comment: i didnt receive any answer,whether it is a bug in wso2 esb

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your single element in an array so that both responses have the same structure. 
$myVar = array('recordSet' => $this->myRecord[0]);